# Multiplication of large numbers python

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-accuracy

I decided to multiply two numbers:
1.0
17299991019999108999910899991119999
and as a result , I received in response:
1.729999101999911e+34

Code:

```
print(1.0*17299991019999108999910899991119999)
1.729999101999911e+34
```

Here I counted it on a calculator:
[image]

Why is python not counting correctly?

Comment: >>> print(1.0*17299991019999108999910899991119999.0) 
1.729999101999911e+34

Comment: Floating-point numbers have limited precision, try using [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) .

Comment: Floating point values are only accurate until the 15th decimal place

Comment: Contrast this with `1 * 17299991019999108999910899991119999` which gives `17299991019999108999910899991119999`, because integers in Python have arbitrary precision.

Comment: >>> from decimal import *    
>>> print(Decimal(1.0) * Decimal(17299991019999108999910899991119999.0))
1.729999101999910967850497553E+34

Comment: You can see more clearly where the floating point precision accuracy is lost by printing all the digits: "{:.4f}".format(17299991019999108999910899991119999) --> '17299991019999109678504975534129152.0000'

Comment: @Kucer0043 the problem with `Decimal(17299991019999108999910899991119999.0)` is that it uses a literal which the parser treats as floating point (so limited precision). You would need `Decimal("17299991019999108999910899991119999.0")` which lets you construct losslessly from a string literal. You would also need to set the precision appropriately high before the calculation, e.g. `getcontext().prec = 50`

Comment: You cannot create a `Decimal` from float and expect it to be precise, because your `172...99.0` is already a float which loses precision immediately...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `1.0` is a `float`, and the rules of Python arithmetic have `float` * `int` = `float`.

[As you should know](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) if you want to do any serious mathematical work, a Python `float` is an [IEEE 754 double-precision number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), and thus (except for “denormals”) has 53 bits (= 15-16 decimal digits) of precision.  The number 17299991019999108999910899991119999 is 114 bits long and thus gets rounded off.

If you need high-precision arithmetic, use the appropriate data type instead of `float`.

- `int` can exactly represent values as large as can fit in your computer's memory.  Of course, it only works for integers, so can't be used for anything with digits after the decimal point.
- [`fractions.Fraction`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) can exactly represent any rational number.  Of course, it won't work for things like square roots, trig functions, and logarithms.
- [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) exactly represents decimal fractions, (e.g., `Decimal('0.01')` really is 0.01 and not 0.01000000000000000020816681711721685132943093776702880859375), and can approximate arbitrary real numbers to a user-specified accuracy (by default, 28 significant digits).  You still get some rounding errors (e.g., 1/3 can't be represented exactly), but less than you get with `float`.